# Will CString's ReleaseBuffer release Shell Allocated CoTaskMemAlloc String?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, com

I believe, from viewing [this](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?520947-MFC-How-to-pass-CString-to-Windows-API-functions) article, I can safely use CStrings to store the returned string results of certain Windows API functions.

For example, I can do the following (not my code, from the article I linked above):

```
   //GetCurrentDirectory gets LPTSTR
   CString strCurDir;
   ::GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, strCurDir.GetBuffer(MAX_PATH));
   strCurDir.ReleaseBuffer();
```

GetCurrentDirectory allocates the data in the "regular" way. I know I could also use an STL wstring to do this as well.

Now my question is, can I safely do *this*?

```
int main()
{
    CString profileRootPath;
    HRESULT result = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Profile, 0, nullptr, (PWSTR*)&profileRootPath);
    wcout << profileRootPath.GetString();
    profileRootPath.ReleaseBuffer();
    Sleep(10000);
    return 0;
}
```

According to SHGetKnownFolderPath's [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx) page, the data output by SHGetKnownFolderPath needs to be de-allocated with a call to CoTaskMemFree. Is the call to ReleaseBuffer invalid because of this? Or will that work properly? Is it not a good idea to use any string class in this case and just use a plain C style array to hold the data, and then use CoTaskMemFree on the array? If the code is invalid, what is the most *correct* way to do this?

Comment: `CString` won't use `CoTaskMemFree` to release the buffer, so this is unsafe and is likely to give troubles.

Comment: `HRESULT result = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Profile, 0, nullptr, (PWSTR*)&profileRootPath);` is a no no !! You cannot cast a `CString` naively to a `PWSTR`. And you probably meant  `(PWSTR)` instead of `(PWSTR*)`. But it's wrong anyway.

Comment: `GetCurrentDirectory` doesn't allocate memory. That's why it's safe to use with any string class. Other Windows API calls do allocate memory (e.g. `FormatMessage` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath`) and you have to use the appropriate allocator to release that memory. String classes can generally not be used in these cases.

Comment: Cool. I'll go ahead and answer my own question with everyone's input. :)

Comment: @IInspectable : `GetCurrentDirectory` with `CString`? I suppose you mean by using `CString::GetBuffer`

Comment: Not related to your question, but use `system("pause")` instead of `Sleep(10000)` (you don't need either of them in release mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ATL the code snippet might be as simple as:

```
CComHeapPtr<WCHAR> pszPath;
HRESULT result = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Profile, 0, nullptr, (PWSTR*) &pszPath);
CString sPath(pszPath);
wcout << sPath.GetString();
```

`~CComHeapPtr` will do `CoTaskMemFree` going out of scope, and `CString` constructor will take the value as `const WCHAR*`.

Without `CComHeapPtr` you can do it like this:

```
WCHAR* pszPath = nullptr;
HRESULT result = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Profile, 0, nullptr, (PWSTR*) &pszPath);
CString sPath(pszPath);
CoTaskMemFree(pszPath);
wcout << sPath.GetString();
```

`GetCurrentDirectory` simply takes your memory pointer to store the string to, so it makes sense to use stack variable because it has zero initialization and cleanup cost. If you need a string, you can build it from stack character array - this eliminates necessity in `ReleaseBuffer` call:

```
TCHAR pszPath[MAX_PATH];
GetCurrentDirectory(_countof(pszPath), pszPath);
CString sPath(pszPath);
```

Comment: That's terribly misleading and right out dangerous advice to **not** call `ReleaseBuffer`. The call is **mandatory**, whenever you call `GetBuffer`. It updates internal data of the `CString` class, to match the new character string. If you don't you may wind up with a `CString` that reports a wrong length, for example.

Comment: Well, you are correct that `GetLength` might report longer string than actual zero-length string value, esp. if the value is then used with indexed access. I took that away. I personally never do `ReleaseBuffer`, but I never do `GetBuffer` either - there is always a cleaner alternative. It would be however a bad idea to not do `ReleaseBuffer` in general.

Comment: Thanks Roman, that looks like exactly what I was looking for, with alternatives. I've marked this as the answer.

Comment: In your first two examples, the `CString` is redundant and fairly useless.  You can this instead: `CComHeapPtr<WCHAR> pszPath; HRESULT result = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Profile, 0, nullptr, &pszPath); wcout << pszPath;`, or this: `WCHAR* pszPath = nullptr; HRESULT result = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Profile, 0, nullptr, &pszPath); wcout << pszPath; CoTaskMemFree(pszPath);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I know but asker wanted CString, why not give it. Here is the thing: it is typical for people to see the way to obtain `CString` object, which they are familiar with, which is well documented and widely used. In this case, it's the way of getting CString from Shell API that returns zero terminated string allocated by COM allocator.

Comment: CString sPath; GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, CStrBuf(sPath,MAX_PATH));

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is simply no, which I figured it would be, since CoTaskMemAlloc is a special way to allocate memory. I'll just stick with the regular way to do things.

```
int main()
{
    WCHAR* profileRootPath = nullptr;
    HRESULT result = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Profile, 0, nullptr, &profileRootPath);
    wcout << profileRootPath;
    CoTaskMemFree(profileRootPath);
    Sleep(10000);
    return 0;
}
```